# Google closure compiler: required entry point "goog" never provided

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I am trying to compile a simple closure project but I am getting this error:

```
build/closure-library/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py:
    Compiling with the following command:
    java -client -jar build/compiler.jar
      --js build/closure-library/closure/goog/base.js
      --js js/index.js
      --manage_closure_dependencies=true
      --transform_amd_modules
      --process_common_js_modules
      --common_js_entry_module
      --common_js_module_path_prefix
      --language_in=ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT
      --compilation_level=SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
ERROR - required entry point "goog" never provided
```

As you can see, the java command is including base.js which has goog defined in it, so I have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I switched from using the bower version of closure-compiler to just cloning that actual source: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler and building it myself, and it worked.